# Project Solution(.sln) is creating in C:/ drive but project created in another drive, how to change the default .sln file saving drive?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, solution

My OS is Windows 7. In my Visual Studio 2012 when I'm creating any project or website the solution file`(.sln)` is creating over default VS folder in C: drive. So when I'm trying to create a project in another drive folder, the solution is not in same folder with the project. How can I change it so that solution file will be in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a check box 'Create a directory for solution' when you create new project, uncheck it.
2. To fix existing solution remove project from solution place all file in solution directory re-add project to solution.
3. To fix existing solution, just close it, move all project folder contents into solution folder, open sln file with text editor and fix project path.

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on .sln file.
2. go to properties then click on change, then select visual studio icon.
3. sln file icon would be same as VS icon, hence problem get solved.